# Determining asymptotic notation of a complex function

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, notation, big-o-notation

$$
5n^4\log{n} - \frac{100n^2}{\log_4(n^2)} + 40
$$

I am currently studying algorithm analysis and i need to express this function in terms of big O, theta and omega, so I should find C, and N0 for each case I solved big Oh with c=40 and n0 = 1 but I am stuck here any help ?

Comment: Can you provide your definition of C and N0? Different definitions use different variable names, so I'm not sure what you mean by them.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the definitions, big-O means "bounded from above" (with a fudging constant $c$ multiplying it all, starting at a high enough $n$), you can disregard "constants multiplying" and "slower growing terms"; so you can say:

$\begin{equation*}
 5 n^2 \log n - \dfrac{100 n^2}{\log_4 n^2} + 40
   = O(n^2 \log n)
\end{equation*}$

(could also say $O(n^3)$, or $O(n^4 \log^{10} n)$ for that matter, *bound from above*).

For a lower bound, the same works fine:

$\begin{equation*}
 5 n^2 \log n - \dfrac{100 n^2}{\log_4 n^2} + 40
   = \Omega(n^2 \log n)
\end{equation*}$

For a lower bound, $\Omega(1)$ or $\Omega(n \log n)$ work fine too.

As you have the same upper/lower bound:

$\begin{equation*}
 5 n^2 \log n - \dfrac{100 n^2}{\log_4 n^2} + 40
   = \Theta(n^2 \log n)
\end{equation*}$

Finding values of $c$ and $N_0$ I leave to you. They *can* be different for $O$ and $\Omega$!

Comment: I understand the concept well, it's the values I got that makes me confuse because after simplifying, I got c, and N0 with the same value which are c = 40 and N0 = 1, just need to know if I am on the right way.